# Is "scancellare" really not correct?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

When I was at the elementary schools, I was taught that *scancellare* is not correct, and that I should always say *cancellare*. When I grew up, I have heard that *scancellare* is correct, and that the initial S is, someway, an intensifier.

Is *scancellare* really correct/acceptable? If it is not in standard Italian, is it acceptable in some contexts? For example, could be acceptable as regionalism?

*Lo Zingarelli 2013* reports *scancellare*, but it says it is *lett. pop.* (I guess it means it is literary and popular.) The application I use on my Mac links *scancellare* to *cancellare*, which means that, looking for *scancellare*, I get the description for *cancellare* with just a small reference to *scancellare*.

> [image: screenshot]

What I am asking is if it is a word I could use in a formal context, during school tests, or similar contexts.

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scancellare/

Comment: To follow up my link: sorry, kiamlaluno, but this is just an example of the kind of “easily answerable” questions I mentioned in a Meta question (http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-we-admit-easily-answerable-questions). A quick lookup in a dictionary reveals that “scancellare” is an actual, if popular, Italian word in use, with modern examples from Luigi Capuana and Eugenio Montale. So it would have been better to do a little research and, if something was still unclear, to ask a more specific question, after summing up what can be easily found out.

Comment: The fact Eugenio Montale used _scancellare_ doesn't mean it can be used in formal writing, or at school, nor that _scancellare_ is not a regionalism.

Comment: Thanks for enriching your question with the Zingarelli reference. Neither of these two dictionaries (nor Devoto-Oli nor DOP) mark the word as “regional”. Do you have some hint that it might be? As for using it in formal writing, it shares with “sé stesso” and several other words and phrases the completely undeserved repute of being “wrong”, so you *might* be scolded (or simply assumed to be something of an ignorant) for using it, again undeservedly.

Comment: Since two dictionaries give a different connotation to the word, I wonder if both the dictionaries are missing something about the usage of the word. I take that _pop._ means _popolare_ as "said from the low class people"; that doesn't say if the word is used in specific regions, or it is equally used in Italy. I just remember that using it in Lombardy would cause you to be looked as an ignorant person.

Comment: For what I saw, all agree that it is “popolare” (and to somebody's ears this translates as “wrong”). As such (popolare), it has been used by some authors who are sensitive to shades of use of words. Where would the dictionaries be missing anything? As for regionalisms, they are generally clearly marked as such in dictionaries (for instance, check in Zingarelli “ravanare” or “pisquano”, marked as “(sett.)”), and “scancellare” is not.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot replace a native speaker, for the simple reason there are nuances in using a word that cannot be described in a dictionary. As native speaker, I still don't understand in which contexts _scancellare_ would be acceptable, since the word could be used to imitate how people without an instruction speak.

Comment: On the other hand, native speakers are biased by their own experience, milieu, idiolect, and pseudo-rules taught in schools. Anyway, your impression that “the word could be used to imitate how people without an instruction speak” is exactly what the “pop.” marking means.

Comment: Don't even bother, 'scancellare' is just *horrible*. I would *never* say or write it. Should I use it while talking to my friends, they would make a fool out of me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would avoid it in anything but informal conversation; the correct Italian form is "cancellare", and in my experience using "scancellare" in formal contexts (or even just in written form) is definitely inappropriate.

Maybe I'm biased because I heard it often in elementary school, but I'd say that, more than a "popular" word, it feels like a childhood word, like other dubious intensives (I remember that at some point we all called the pencil sharpener "attemperamatite" instead of "temperamatite" :) ).

Answer (score 7):

In Italian the *s-* prefix has two functions:

1. denote the opposite action, like in *tappare/stappare*, *mettere/smettere*
2. denote an “intensive” action, like in

   - *forzare/sforzare*
   - *correre/scorrere*
   - *calciare/scalciare*

The three “intensified” verbs above denote a slight different action, but nobody would interpret *scorrere* with the meaning *not be running*.

For a horse we'd use *scalciare* rather than *calciare* (both mean *to kick*). I see no reason for prohibiting the two usages

- Cancella quello cha hai scritto (erase what you wrote)
- Ho scancellato la lavagna (I erased the blackboard)

where the intensive prefix has its function to denote a “personal” action, like for the horse that *scalcia*.

The word *scancellare* has centuries of history: the [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scancellare/) reports it being used by Poliziano (1454-1494). The war against it made in elementary schools is really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is popular and most time considered an error.
Moreover, in Italian you have words that get opposite meaning if you add an S at the beginning: tappare/Stappare, chiudere/Schiudere, fatto/Sfatto so if you follow this line scancellare should be interpreted as "undelete". Of course when used it has the meaning of delete, therefore scancellare is both popular and not so logical.

Comment: Your argument does not really hold, as [undelete is a neologism](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undelete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cundelete%3B%2Cc0), born with computers (once you delete something on paper it's gone, so *undelete* really did not have any meaning in the past). *Scancellare*, on the other hand, was used in the past as pointed out by the other answers.